# Is it possible to get AptX Adaptive Bluetooth connectivity working natively with Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

I'm trying to find a way to seamlessly connect my AptX Adaptive headset to my PC using the native Windows 10 Bluetooth settings, whilst making full use of the AptX Adaptive codec, such as low latency and higher quality audio.

Looking at the BT-W4, as well as all the other AptX adaptive dongles on Amazon, they all have this button on the top which makes me think you'll just be pairing directly to the dongle. Ideally, I want a device that just integrates with Windows Bluetooth settings, so headphones pair easily, and will automatically switch audio outputs when I turn them on. My current Asus dongle does this, but it's only Bluetooth 4, and doesn't support any kind of Apt X low latency.

Does such a device exist?

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not support AptX Adaptive in its Bluetooth stack, most likely for licensing reasons. Bluetooth dongles -- that is, external network cards -- won't help with this. The dongles that support AptX Adaptive are actually external *sound cards* -- in Windows, they appear as a sound device, and act similarly to wired headphones. The encoding is then handled in the sound card, and the Bluetooth device is connected using the sound card's own Bluetooth receiver.

So no, you can't have the best of both worlds -- either you rely on Windows' Bluetooth stack which does not support AptX Adaptive, or you use an external sound card which manages its own Bluetooth stack.